# Deploying RoR app with Passenger: Apache shows files only from public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, permissions, directory, passenger

I am a newbie in both Rails and Apache stuff. I followed tutorials to create new rails app, and tried to deploy it using Passenger.

I generated a scaffold, created+migrated database and, and it is already working on localhost:3000.

I installed apache2 and passenger, enabled mod passenger, and I can see the usual "Welcome aboard/You’re riding Ruby on Rails!" page on localhost:80 also. But I can't reach the localhost/posts page, while I can reach localhost:3000/posts. (I see "500 Internal Server Error" page, not one of the 404/422/500 pages in the public folder). I also don't see the rails image on the index page (assets/rails.png) on port #80 -everything is OK on port #3000.

I added RackEnv developer and RailsEnv developer to the virtual host file. Apache gives no error output on screen when I restart it -It reasonably gives error when I say a2dismod passenger: "Invalid command 'RackEnv'". So I assume passenger is working.

I believe somehow apache is not reading the folders except for the public folder, I tried playing around with the permissions and ownerships with no success.

Anybody has a clue?

Thanks

EDIT: I did

rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production
rake db:migrate:reset RAILS_ENV=production

and the deleted the RackEnv/RailsEnv lines from the vhost file, and restarted apache. Now I see public/500.html on localhost/posts. it is still working on localhost:3000/posts

Logs: rails log file contains only

Migrating to CreateDenemes (20120316021657)

apache error log

[Thu Mar 15 22:22:03 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Mar 15 22:22:03 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Mar 15 22:22:04 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/3.0.11 mod_ssl/2.2.20 OpenSSL/1.0.0e configured -- resuming normal operation
s

and other_vhosts...log is empty

V host file:

VirtualHost *:80

```
  ServerName sencer

  DocumentRoot /home/sselcuk/sencer/public

  Directory /home/sselcuk/sencer/public

     AllowOverride all              

     Options -MultiViews           

  /Directory
```

/VirtualHost

Comment: Are you running this locally? If so I believe you need the `:3000` in all urls.

Comment: Please post your Apache config for this virtual host / port.

Comment: Did you add the following code to your apache config file , such as /etc/apache2/httpd.conf ? 
`LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8` ?

Comment: I did. And log file already says passenger/3.0.11 is working

Comment: Now apache error log says:


cache: [GET /assets/rails.png] miss
cache: [GET /assets/rails.png] miss

Comment: sencer did you ever solve this problem, as I appear to be running into the same problem?

Comment: I actually did, but I don't remember how :/

Answer (score 1):

I need your log files, both Rails and apache log.

1. Rails log file:  see:  RAILS_ROOT/log/production.log
2. apache log file:  see /var/log/apache2  (  in ubuntu)

once getting that information, we can debug for you.

Comment: rails log file contains only

Migrating to CreateDenemes (20120316021657)

apache error log


[Thu Mar 15 22:22:03 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Mar 15 22:22:03 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Mar 15 22:22:04 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/3.0.11 mod_ssl/2.2.20 OpenSSL/1.0.0e configured -- resuming normal operation
s

and other_vhosts...log is empty